# Configure 2 LANs with different classes or force AP to assign IP to his connected devices

Tags: networking, router, wireless-access-point

Sorry for the title.

Current scenario:

`Internet > Fritz!Box 7530 192.168.1.x > AP TpLink TL-WA801N with IP 192.168.1.2 > so many devices`

Fritz has DHCP enabled, from 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.90.

TP-Link has DHCP disabled.

Some devices connect to the Fritbox! Wifi (smartphones, tablet, etc). Let's call `FRITZ-WIFI`.

Some devices connect to the TPLink Wifi (Shellies / Tasmota / Cameras, etc). Let's call `AP-WIFI`.

I tried some attempt:

1. Set a static IP from TP Link for "shelly 1" (192.168.1.110). No success... Shelly connected to AP-WIFI got IP from the Fritz (!).
2. Removed every pre-assigned IP, new Shelly on LAN, connected to `AP-WIFI`... got IP from Fritz.

The Fritz wins every time, so I need to put fixed IP on the Fritz itself.

My goal is have my stuffes (shellies, Raspberries, etc) linked to my personal AP TpLink, and leave Fritz only for other stuffes. Because I could change router / ISP every time and no-redo my LAN configuration.

I would create 2 classes of IP (192.168.0 for my domotics stuffs) but... I have no competence to manage 2 classes and talk from class 1 to class 2 and viceversa.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two IP classes as AP is not a router. There are combined devices router+AP, but I have googled the documentation for the AP model you mentioned and this one isn't. AP is more like a switch, so it's nothing strange that devices connecting to your TPLink get the IP address from Fritz's DHCP. They are all in the same subnet.

If you want some devices connect only to TPLink's WiFi, and others only to Fritz's WiFi, you have to use MAC address filtering. From the documentation it looks that both should support it. If you want for example some specific devices connect to Fritz, and all others to TPLink, add only MAC adddresses of these devices to the MAC address filter list on Fritz, and deny access to the same MAC addresses on TPLink. Then the specified devices would be able to connect only to Fritz, and all other devices would be able to connect only to TPLink.

Probably you can't do it the other way, because from what I see in the documentation there is no option to deny access to particular MAC addresses on Fritz, only allow. But you should check for yourself, the documentation may be incomplete.

Also, if you want fixed IP for some devices, you have to assign them on Fritz, as it is providing DHCP for the entire network, regardless of where the devices are connected. Or disable DHCP on Fritz and enable it on TPLink, if DHCP on TPLink is able to operate on both wireless and wired interface (you cannot have two DHCP servers in the same network segment).